# jQuery Mobile - Loading External HTML

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm loading some external html into a div in a jquery mobile app. Everything works fine, however I'm trying to make it a little bit smoother.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function (event, ui) {
    if (event.target.id == 'pageViewOrder') {
        //get the page
        $.getJSON(root_url + '/orders/view/' + window.viewOrderReference + '/?callback=?', null, function (d) {
            $("#viewOrder_content").html(d.html).trigger("create");
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        });
    }
```

What's happening is the page is being displayed prior to the ajax call finishing. Is there a way of halting jquery mobile from proceeding to display the page before this call is finished? At the moment it shows the page then the content pops in.

**EDIT:** This is loading in single pages

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Halting the display process is easy, you just need to call `event.preventDefault()`.
The problem is then to make sure that you will go with the process once you retrieve your content. What I would actually do is bind to `pagechange`, check if you have already retrieved the data, if not, then interrupt the process, retrieve the data and start over. If yes, then proceed as planned.

```
var contentRetrieved = false; //will indicate wether the JSON call has already been executed
var contentToDisplay; //data from the JSON call

$(document).live('pagebeforechange', function (event, data) {
    if (( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) && ($.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage).hash == '#pageViewOrder')) {
        if (contentRetrieved) {
           contentRetrieved = false; //content is already retrieved, we proceed with the pagechange
        } else {
           event.preventDefault(); //prevent further page change operations
           $.getJSON(root_url + '/orders/view/' + window.viewOrderReference + '/?callback=?', null, function (d) {
                contentToDisplay = {"html":d.html};
                contentRetrieved = true;
                $.mobile.changePage("#pageViewOrder");
            });
        }
    }
});


$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function (event, ui) {
    if (event.target.id == 'pageViewOrder') {
        $("#viewOrder_content").html(contentToDisplay.html).trigger("create");
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }
});​
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried your code but I get the following error:

TypeError: contentToDisplay is undefined

Comment: Same problem... I did some alerts and for some reason, pagebeforecreate is being called BEFORE pagebeforechange.... hmmm

Comment: Actually this will happen if your page is the first page, as no changepage has been called. IF you navigate to the page though, there shouldn't be any problem